# TouchDelegate not receiving tap events correctly

Tags: android, view

Edit: This problem was down to me passing the wrong view to the Touch Delegate...problem is resolved now....

My `RelativeLayout` extension enlarges the clickable area of an `ImageView`. The RelativeLayout is the root `View` of the `ListView` row. The problem is when tapping areas that should be delegated to the `ImageView`, the `ListView`'s `onItemClicked` is triggered.

My code is at the end and below is an image of what the extended bounds of the `ImageView` should be. If I tap on blue areas that are *not* the image, the click is received by the `ListView`.

[image: Blue areas indicate new bounds of the ImageView]

```
public class DelegatingRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

//relevant code moved to top
@Override 
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    final float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int extra = (int) (density * 4 + 0.5f);

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, mEnlargedView.getWidth(), getHeight());
    rect.right += extra; //extend bounds by 4 pixels
    setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(rect, mEnlargedView));
    mExtendedBounds = rect;
}

public void setEnlargedView(View v) {       
    mEnlargedView = v;
}

private static final boolean DEBUG_DRAW = true;

private View mEnlargedView;
private Rect mExtendedBounds;

//constructors removed

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (DEBUG_DRAW) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(mExtendedBounds, p);
    }

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}

}
```

Comment: where do you set the OnClickListener for your RelativeLayout?

Comment: I don't set an onClickListener, the DelegatingRelativeLayout is the root element of the xml layout file for ListView rows. I've used the ideas mentioned here: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=574

Comment: For the ImageView, I see the onClickListener in my Adapter's getView method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I've just realized I've been passing the wrong view to the touch delegate >.< It's been working fine now.... >.<